Control-M AFT job failing with "Failed in listFilteredFiles" and "no such file or directory" when permissions and directory path are correct
I'm working with someone who is trying to test some file transfers in a Control-M TEST environment but it keeps failing despite the service accounts having full permissions. The two messages I've seen in the output from these failures are that it either thinks the file or directory doesn't exist OR that it "Failed in listFilteredFiles".
I've tried testing with simply using a wildcard (*) to pick up any and all files but it fails with a message in the output that says "Failed in listFilteredFiles" (but it doesn't say there isn't a file or directory when we do it this way).
When we try to specify anything in the file name such as "*.txt" or a portion of the file name, it fails saying there is "no such file or directory" but doesn't have the "listFilteredFiles" error message.
When I attempt this transfer in our production environment, it works just fine.
We've checked permissions in this directory and there's full read, write, execute permissions for the service accounts we're using. I'm stumped and can't find anything online when I try to research similar issues.
Any input on what could be causing this? I'm not sure if this is something that needs to be fixed with the directory or if it's some type of configuration issue with the agent/control-m test server. Thanks!
